# How to make two AlertDialog appear one after the other in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a two AlertDialog two appear one after the other. One for getting Username and another for getting password. So, here when I run this, I'm getting an application crash. I'm quite new to Android Studio. Here's my code.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            final EditText text = new EditText(this);

            builder1.setTitle("Username").setMessage("Please enter your name.").setView(text);
            builder1.setPositiveButton("Apply", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                    final String name_from_alert = text.getText().toString(); 
                }
            });
            // disables outside touch cancel
            builder1.setCancelable(false);
            builder1.create().show();


            // getting password
            builder2.setTitle("Password").setMessage("Please enter a password").setView(text);
            builder2.setPositiveButton("Apply", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface di, int i) {
                    final String password_from_alert = text.getText().toString();
                }
            });
            // disables outside touch cancel
            builder2.setCancelable(false);
            builder2.create().show();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. What's crashing? You forgot your logcat. 2. Why not ask for username and password in the same dialog? That's generally how it's done.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Definitely I'll attach the logcat in future confusions. And thanks for the hint. Yea! Just done it that way. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take Custom layout for your Dialog :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#056FB4">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edUsername"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Username"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textPersonName"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="#c2b098"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edPassword"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:capitalize="sentences"
        android:maxLength="20"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textColorHint="#c2b098"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <Button
        android:text="Ok"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edBoxName"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java file :

```
 public void openDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
    final EditText edUsername = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edUsername);
    final EditText edPassword = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.edPassword);
    Button btnDissmissDialog = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnOk);
    btnDissmissDialog.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (dialog != null) {
                if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                        String strUsername = edUsername.getText().toString().trim();
                        String strPasswird = edPassword.getText().toString().trim();
                        dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This has been the perfect way to do it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and then extend `DialogFragment` class and then override its `OnCreateDialog()` method, then you create a static method to create an instance and pass arguments.

The OnCreateDialog

```
 @Override
 public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
 //set title,message or view ....

 // when you done
 return dialog.create();
 }
```

The static method to put arguments ( Static Factory Pattern Design )

```
public static CustomAlertDialog newInstance(String title,String message) {
CustomAlertDialog customAD = new CustomAlertDialog();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("title", title);
args.putString("message", message);
customAD.setArguments(args);
return customAD;
}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
DialogFragment dialog = CustomAlertDialog.newInstance("titulo","message");
dialog.show(/* etc.. */ );
```